# I get errors in my MainActivity.java for no reason

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am "trying" to make a calculator in eclpse for android and i get all these errors for no reason this is my MainActivity

```
package com.odysseus.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    } //here

    if(num1text.getText().toString().isEmpty()  || num2text.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You Should Put Numbers To Do Calculation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
    }
//EDIT ok last problem is here with else underlines { and if add another one on the bottom says delete this token...
else
{
public void calcadd(View v){ //here
        EditText number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        EditText number2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2text);
        Integer num1text=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());Integer num2text=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans=num1text+num2text;

        TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:"+ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcaminus(View v){ //here
        EditText number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        EditText number2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2text);
        Integer num1text=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());Integer num2text=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans=num1text-num2text;

        TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:"+ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcadivide(View v){ //here
        EditText number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        EditText number2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2text);
        Integer num1text=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());Integer num2text=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans=num1text/num2text;

        TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:"+ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcmultiply(View v){ //here
        EditText number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        EditText number2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2text);
        Integer num1text=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());Integer num2text=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans=num1text*num2text;

        TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:"+ans.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { //here
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } 

}
```

These are the problems:

```
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected   MainActivity.java   /Calculator/src/com/odysseus/calculator line 37 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected   MainActivity.java   /Calculator/src/com/odysseus/calculator line 27 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected   MainActivity.java   /Calculator/src/com/odysseus/calculator line 47 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected   MainActivity.java   /Calculator/src/com/odysseus/calculator line 37 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected   MainActivity.java   /Calculator/src/com/odysseus/calculator line 27 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected   MainActivity.java   /Calculator/src/com/odysseus/calculator line 47 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected   MainActivity.java   /Calculator/src/com/odysseus/calculator line 57 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected   MainActivity.java   /Calculator/src/com/odysseus/calculator line 57 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected   MainActivity.java   /Calculator/src/com/odysseus/calculator line 68 Java Problem
```

Also check if it has any more mistakes that i will see when i run the app thanks in advance! :)
EDIT see on else for my last problem also corrected the code thanks to @kathir
EDIT OK ISSUE RESOLVED THANKS EVERYBODY

Comment: usually you will not get errors because of no reason...

Comment: @Reimeus can you explain a bit more i am new to eclipse

Comment: @Reimeus i still got problem with else { underlines bracket and if i add one more below to close since that's it tells me to do says delete token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should be,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (num1text.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                || num2text.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "You Should Put Numbers To Do Calculation",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        } else {
        }
    }

    public void calcadd(View v) { // here
        EditText number1text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        EditText number2text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2text);
        Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
        Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans = num1text + num2text;

        TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcaminus(View v) { // here
        EditText number1text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        EditText number2text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2text);
        Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
        Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans = num1text - num2text;

        TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcadivide(View v) { // here
        EditText number1text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        EditText number2text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2text);
        Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
        Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans = num1text / num2text;

        TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcmultiply(View v) { // here
        EditText number1text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        EditText number2text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2text);
        Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
        Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans = num1text * num2text;

        TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // here
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: omg thanks you had some mistakes too! xD but ok i corrected them but thanks even you should kind of explain my mistakes so i can correct them myself but still thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In line marked

```
} //here
```

you just "closed" `onCreate()` so all the code below is invalid. You need to remove that bracket. Also it must be `else`, not `Else`

Comment: If i delete that then num1text and num2text on if have errors again

Answer (score 1):

Your if else is outside of any method.

`Else` should be `else`

Your  `EditText number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);` is initialized in the else part.

You need to initialize your views in `onCreate`

```
EditText number1text,number2text;
TextView answer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
    number2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2text);
    answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans); 
} 
 public void calcaminus(View v){ 
  if(num1text.getText().toString().isEmpty()  || num2text.getText().toString().isEmpty())
     {
      // your toast message
     }
    else
    {
    Integer num1text=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
    Integer num2text=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
    Integer ans=num1text+num2text;
    answer.setText("Answer:"+ans.toString());
    }
} 
...// rest of the methods.
```

There is no need to initialize you views on click everytime. Initialize in onCreate once.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have closed your `onCreate` without including if-else
   that is, in this line:

   ```
   }//here
   ```
2. `Else` should be small caps, that is:

   ```
   else
   {

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.odysseus.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText number1text;
EditText number2text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        number2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2text);


    if(num1text.getText().toString().isEmpty()  || num2text.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You Should Put Numbers To Do Calculation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
    }
//if i put here else it show an error again help me on that too
else
{
public void calcadd(View v){ //here

        Integer num1text=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());Integer num2text=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans=num1text+num2text;

        TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:"+ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcaminus(View v){ //here

        Integer num1text=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());Integer num2text=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans=num1text-num2text;

        TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:"+ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcadivide(View v){ //here

        Integer num1text=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());Integer num2text=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans=num1text/num2text;

        TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:"+ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcmultiply(View v){ //here

        Integer num1text=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());Integer num2text=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans=num1text*num2text;

        TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:"+ans.toString());
    }

} //here



}
```

Try it out dude :)

Comment: one thing, in all methods you set text to same textview.
and you need to call methos by button or any other things.

Comment: Everything is wrong in yours frnd. smthing ,. very confusing. learn clearly and start trying.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? xD i am new

Comment: first create buttons to do calculation, and for each button give you code in calcadd, calcbub nd so on in that. 
If you click that , it do additon , subtraction, nd so operations.

Comment: I did that on my xml i put android:onClick="calcadd" isn't that what you mean?